# dplyr: Create new column based on rows from another column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am currently trying to modify a data frame in R and I am wondering if there is a possibility to do so with a dplyr code. I am aiming at creating a new column that combines the entries from three rows each of the 'text' column. My data looks like this:

```
        source       xmin       xmax            text  dur  
   1    FR1_   0.465000   0.725000            tour  260 
   2    FR1_  0.725000    0.805000              de   80  
   3    FR1_   0.805000   1.175000            rôle  370 
   4    FR1_   3.418440   3.608440           pomme  190 
   5    FR1_   3.608440   3.728440              de  120  
   6    FR1_   3.728440   4.128440           terre  400 
   7    FR1_   5.586440   6.066440         colonie  480 
   8    FR1_   6.066440   6.196440              de  130  
   9    FR1_  6.196440    6.796440        vacances  600
```

and I am aiming to create a new column 'word' that looks like this :

```
     source       xmin       xmax            text  dur     word
   1    FR1_   0.465000   0.725000            tour  260   tour de rôle
   2    FR1_  0.725000   0.805000              de   80    tour de rôle
   3    FR1_   0.805000   1.175000            rôle  370   tour de rôle
   4    FR1_   3.418440   3.608440           pomme  190   pomme de terre
   5    FR1_   3.608440   3.728440              de  120   pomme de terre
   6    FR1_   3.728440   4.128440           terre  400   pomme de terre
   7    FR1_   5.586440   6.066440         colonie  480  colonie de vacances
   8    FR1_   6.066440   6.196440              de  130  colonie de vacances
   9    FR1_  6.196440   6.796440        vacances  600   colonie de vacances
```

I would appreciate any kind of suggestions!

Comment: Please provide an example dataset, and an example of the output you'd like to see from that example dataset

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I hope you can now see my example properly.

Comment: Yes, in fact they are always in groups of three (but the data frame in total is much larger than the example I displayed here).

Answer (score 0):

dplyr doesn't like to operate on multi-rows units determined by row index alone. So the first step is to create a variable that we can use to group the rows into clusters of three. Then we can use a standard `group_by()` and `muatate()` to gernate the new column. For example

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% 
  mutate(cluster=(1:n()-1)%/%3) %>% 
  group_by(cluster) %>% 
  mutate(word=paste(text, collapse=" ")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-cluster)
```

This works with the sample data

```
dd<-read.table(text="        source       xmin       xmax            text  dur  
   1    FR1_   0.465000   0.725000            tour  260 
   2    FR1_  0.725000    0.805000              de   80  
   3    FR1_   0.805000   1.175000            rôle  370 
   4    FR1_   3.418440   3.608440           pomme  190 
   5    FR1_   3.608440   3.728440              de  120  
   6    FR1_   3.728440   4.128440           terre  400 
   7    FR1_   5.586440   6.066440         colonie  480 
   8    FR1_   6.066440   6.196440              de  130  
   9    FR1_  6.196440    6.796440        vacances  600", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, your code works perfectly. I have one last question. I realized that there is still one row in the initial data frame that I want to delete before performing your code. It is row number 412. Can you tell me how to omit it?

Comment: start with `dd %>% slice(-412)` to drop that row first

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work for my data frame. The problem is that I have for some reason one row without any text in it. So perhaps it would be possible to delete all rows without any text. I tried this command     
        segs_df2 [ ! ( segs_df2$text =="") , ]                                                     , but it did not work properly.

Comment: If you are having a different problem, you should probably create a better reproducible example and start a new question.

Comment: You are right, I'll first try to find a post that explains my new problem and in case there is no related question, I'll start a new question.

Comment: Thank you again for all your help. I just solved my problem by using this code   
       segs_df%>%  filter(!text=="") %>%